# Enforce order on composite primary key

Tags: mysql

Say I have the following table

```
item_a_id, item_b_id, value
```

Where item_a_id and item_b_id are a composite primary key. In my example a,b and b,a are equivalent. Therefore I want to ensure that item_a_id < item_b_id. Obviously the application logic will enforce this but is there a way to ensure the database does too?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In a reasonably current version of MySql you can use triggers to [emulate a check constraint](http://forge.mysql.com/wiki/Triggers#Emulating_Check_Constraints) that produces the desired behavior.

Answer (score 2):

Well, in your case, you could use trigger to check values before insert/update and swap it to ensure `item_a_id` will always less than `item_b_id`.

Assuming the table name is `item_links`, you could try this:

```
DELIMITER |

CREATE TRIGGER ensure_a_b_before_insert BEFORE INSERT ON item_links
  FOR EACH ROW 
  BEGIN
    IF NEW.item_a_id > NEW.item_b_id THEN
      SET @tmp = NEW.item_b_id;
      SET NEW.item_b_id = NEW.item_a_id;
      SET NEW.item_a_id = @tmp;
    END IF;
  END;
|

CREATE TRIGGER ensure_a_b_before_update BEFORE UPDATE ON item_links
  FOR EACH ROW 
  BEGIN
    IF NEW.item_a_id > NEW.item_b_id THEN
      SET @tmp = NEW.item_b_id;
      SET NEW.item_b_id = NEW.item_a_id;
      SET NEW.item_a_id = @tmp;
    END IF;
  END;
|

DELIMITER ;
```

Here's what I got when I test inserting:

```
mysql> INSERT INTO  `item_links` (`item_a_id`, `item_b_id`, `value`)
    -> VALUES ('1',  '2',  'a')
    ->      , ('3',  '2',  'b')
    ->      , ('4',  '1',  'c');
Query OK, 3 rows affected (0.01 sec)
Records: 3  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0

mysql> SELECT * FROM `item_links`;
+-----------+-----------+-------+
| item_a_id | item_b_id | value |
+-----------+-----------+-------+
|         1 |         2 | a     |
|         2 |         3 | b     |
|         1 |         4 | c     |
+-----------+-----------+-------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Update works, too:

```
mysql> UPDATE `item_links` 
    -> SET `item_a_id` = 100, `item_b_id` = 20 
    -> WHERE `item_a_id` = 1 AND `item_b_id` = 2;
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.03 sec)
Rows matched: 1  Changed: 1  Warnings: 0

mysql> SELECT * FROM `item_links`;
+-----------+-----------+-------+
| item_a_id | item_b_id | value |
+-----------+-----------+-------+
|        20 |       100 | a     |
|         2 |         3 | b     |
|         1 |         4 | c     |
+-----------+-----------+-------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```